# Giving Superuser access to all Users in a GROUP

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is it possible to grant superuser access to anyone in a GROUP?
I have created a GROUP for Admins and we authenticate through IAM roles and a USER GROUP. I'm trying to give superaccess to anyone who connect within that Admin Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours, came to conclusion that there is no way to give superuser access to a user group.